# How to edit XML in Android and save?

Tags: android, xml, save, sax, edit

I have an XML file, as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<TODO-LIST>

<MYTASK TIME = "10:00">
 Meeting
</MYTASK>

<MYTASK TIME = "11:00">
Lecture
</MYTASK>


<MYTASK TIME = "12:00">
 Lunch
</MYTASK>
```

And so on...

I can read it from res/xml folder using,

```
   Resources res = activity.getResources();
   XmlResourceParser xpp = res.getXml(R.xml.tv_editor_todo_list);
   xpp.next();
   int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
   while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
   {
    if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT)
    {
     stringBuffer.append("--- Start XML ---");

    }
    else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
    {
     stringBuffer.append("\nSTART_TAG: "+xpp.getName());

     ...
```

My question how can I edit and update the XML file on the fly, for example, say change,

```
<MYTASK TIME = "10:00">
 Meeting
</MYTASK>
```

to

```
<YOURTASK TIME = "11:30">
 Reading
</YOURTASK>
```

And save the file back?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot modify files that are stored in the res folder during runtime. You'll need to store your xml file either in your applications internal storage, or on the SDCard if you want to be able to modify and re-save.

Something like this will give you an optoutStream to your internal storage.

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("yourfile.xml", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

Comment: Thanks much for the info.

OK, please let me rephrase my question a little bit. If I read the file form the res/xml, and I agree and want to save on SDCard. Still, I am in dark, how can I change those values in the question above? Any idea?

Comment: You get the values using your code (`Resources res = activity.getResources();...`), then save it to a file, and from now on you will have to parse the file instead of looking at the resource file.